# Can't Create Database with Create Database Command

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I installed Oracle 19c Database software. Im trying to create a database with script;
Im created a listener and pfile (parameter) file.
Then type this commands,

--> #sqlplus / as sysdba
--> SQL> startup nomount

After that;

--> CREATE DATABASE DBNAME

When i type this commands, im getting just "2" on the screen. And then, anything does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

the "2" is just SQL Plus saying "I am waiting for you to type into line 2" and so on...

However, I would recommend using the Database Configuration Assistant to create a database. On Windows its on the Start menu, and on Unix it is "dbca" available from $ORACLE_HOME/bin.

If you really want to *manually* create a database, the commands look similar to something like this

```
CREATE DATABASE mynewdb
   USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY sys_password
   USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY system_password
   LOGFILE GROUP 1 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo01.log') SIZE 100M,
           GROUP 2 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo02.log') SIZE 100M,
           GROUP 3 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo03.log') SIZE 100M
   MAXLOGFILES 5
   MAXLOGMEMBERS 5
   MAXLOGHISTORY 1
   MAXDATAFILES 100
   CHARACTER SET US7ASCII
   NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16
   EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
   DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/system01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
   SYSAUX DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
   DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
      DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/users01.dbf'
      SIZE 500M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
   DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tempts1
      TEMPFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/temp01.dbf'
      SIZE 20M REUSE
   UNDO TABLESPACE undotbs
      DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/undotbs01.dbf'
      SIZE 200M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

but (with no disrepect intended) if you're new to Oracle, then use the configuration assistant to get up and running.

Here's a video walkthrough on the steps involved.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl_90YYVA10

Answer (score 1):

The CREATE DATABASE command requires a LOT more parameters. Here's an example:

```
CREATE DATABASE test
USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY manager
USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY manager
LOGFILE GROUP 1 (‘/u01/test/redo01.log’) SIZE 50M,
GROUP 2 (‘/u01/test/redo02.log’) SIZE 50M,
GROUP 3 (‘/u01/test/redo03.log’) SIZE 50M
MAXLOGFILES 5
MAXLOGMEMBERS 5
MAXLOGHISTORY 50
MAXDATAFILES 100
MAXINSTANCES 1
DATAFILE ‘/u01/test/system01.dbf’ SIZE 100M autoextend on
SYSAUX DATAFILE ‘/u01/test/sysaux01.dbf’ SIZE 100M autoextend on
DEFAULT TABLESPACE users datafile ‘/u01/test/users01.dbf’ size 100m autoextend on
DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
TEMPFILE ‘/u01/test/temp01.dbf’ SIZE 50m
UNDO TABLESPACE undotbs1
DATAFILE ‘/u01/test/undotbs01.dbf’
SIZE 200M;
```

You should read up on the syntax, study some tutorials and make sure you are setting all of the options you need for your specific environment. Here's a couple of other links:

- https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/oracle-db-19c-installation-on-oracle-linux-7#database-creation
- https://oracledbwr.com/manually-creating-an-oracle-19c-database/
- http://www.ocptechnology.com/create-manual-database-in-oracle-19c/
- https://dbaclass.com/article/how-to-create-a-database-manually/